# Redirect from one Razor View to another Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, xamarin.android, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to Razor Views and I am working on Xamarin studio, making a hybrid application that works only on WebView.

Long story short, I am not working with MVC. No models and no controllers here, only Razor Views. Now this might be a wrong question, but is it possible to navigate from one razor view to another??

Like, from one .cshtml to another .cshtml, without going through any Controller, because I don't have Controllers.

Any .NET helper like, `@Html.ActionLink("Text", "someFolder/page2.cshtml");`

**Update 1**

Screenshots of index.cshtml and MainActivity.cs, from which I am generating HTML for index:

[image]

[image]

The breakpoint is on the line that is generating the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot redirect to another view without calling action.

In asp.net mvc you have actions and against actions View is returned, we can show two views in a view without calling action but cannot redirect to some view without calling action.

If you don't need controllers then you are not following mvc architecture so then i would prefer to use simple html pages, there is no need to use mvc in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60232/discussion-between-asadullah-and-ehsan-sajjad).

Answer (score 0):

you can use PartialView as shown below but it will just use one view in another view  it does not redirect to another view as you have mentioned :-

```
@Html.Partial("~/YourPath", Model);
```

For more information :- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC